# Hibernate and java heap space error

Tags: java, hibernate, heap-memory

I have a Stock and StockRecords classes with one to many relationship.

In  Stock.hbm.xml , i have a collection defined like this

```
<bag name="stockRecords" table="stockRecords" inverse="true" lazy="true"
  fetch="select">
<key>
    <column name="stock_Records" not-null="true" />
</key>
    <one-to-many class="com.my.model.objects.StockRecords" /> 
</bag>
```

I am accesing one stock at a time. here is the problem

Stockrecords has one filed (String type) which will contain 500000 characters in it on an average

In StockRecords.hbm.xml

```
<property name="summary" type="string" lazy="true"  >
        <column name="summary" />
    </property>
```

While i am accesing one of the stock entity based on id, i am trying to build a string of all the summary fields from all the stock records of that stock. I am getting java heap space error her i have my jvm setting set to 512m. is this hibernate or java thing?

hibernate 4.xx
java 1.7

Comment: May be you will need to change 512m to 1024m. That might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you purge the entities from the Hibernate context with `session.evict(obj)` as soon as you don't need it anymore. Otherwise all these entities will fill your memory quite quickly.

You can also clear the whole context with `session.clear()` if being agressive is not an issue for your algorithm.

If this is not enough, you should consider increasing the Java heap size.